# .FormulaR1C1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs Arguments not working

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use a countifs statement by looking in the first 2 columns and comparing them to another table in the same Wokbook. The reference RrC1, RC1 or anything else does not work. I only get "0" as a result. If i type in constants it works. I'm sure that my arguments 2, 4, 6 are the problem. I just can' figure out why!

```
Sub DataBase()

'Set my tables
    Dim Answers As ListObject
    Dim Table As ListObject
    Set Answers = Worksheets("quantitativ").ListObjects("DataQuant")
    Set Table = Worksheets("Database").ListObjects("Tabelle7")

'Set my Ranges for filters (Organizational level, Location, Function...)
    
    Set OrgRange = Answers.ListColumns(1).Range
    Set LocRange = Answers.ListColumns(2).Range

'Set Ranges for Answers to Questions (Scale)
Set Q1 = Answers.ListColumns(5).Range

Dim r As Long    'Row variables for For-Loop

    For r = 5 To Table.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count + 4
      
        'Q1
        Cells(r, 6).FormulaR1C1 = _
            Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q1, RrC5, OrgRange, RrC1, LocRange, RrC2)
    
    Next r
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cells(r, 6).FormulaR1C1 = _
Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q1, RrC5, OrgRange, RrC1, LocRange, RrC2)
```

This is quite a mess. You're attempting to load a formula with the ***result*** of a worksheet function.

---

If you want to load the formula to the cell then I'd do this:

```
Cells(r, 6).Formula = "=CountIfs(" & Q1.Address & ", " & _
  Cells(r, 5).Address & ", " & OrgRange.Address & ", " & _
  Cells(r, 1).Address & ", " & LocRange.Address & ", " & _
  Cells(r, 2).Address & ")"
```

Or even:

```
Cells(r, 6).Formula = .Formula = "=CountIfs(" & _
       Q1.Address & ", E" & r & ", " & _
 OrgRange.Address & ", A" & r & ", " & _
 LocRange.Address & ", B" & r & ")"
```

---

However, if you want the formula evaluated and just the result dumped in the cell..

```
Cells(r, 6).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q1, _
    Cells(R, 5), OrgRange, Cells(R, 1), LocRange, Cells(R, 2))
```

---

Keep in mind though with all of these options, `Cells(..` are not fully qualified.

Changing all to `.Cells(..` would make this much better, wrapping the lot 
in a

`With WorkSheet("DESTINATION_SHEET") 
 ...
 ...
 End With`

is highly advisable.

Comment: Thank you very very much! This helped and worked perfectly!